# What is the archaic version of the verb conjugation しても？

Tags: grammar

What is the archaic version of the verb conjugation しても？

Comment: I feel as though it's something like せど or しえど but I'm not sure.

Comment: I think I found the answer ........... すれども。  I imagine that すれど is essentially the same. Thank you to anyone who has read my question and is considering an answer! I hunted a bit after I posted the question and found some information sources for classical Japanese.

Comment: You have answered your own question.

Comment: @Jerry Can put the answer below so it wont show up on the unanswered page?

Comment: Perhaps the mods should close this instead... less unanswered posts.